# Remove len list if not Number/Digit Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I have random list data like this

```
data = 
[['No','Name','Job'],
['1','A','A'],
['2','B','B'],
['IS','NOT','NUMBER'],
['3','C','C']]
```

as you can see if i `print(len(data))` it will print **5**

> how i remove data list and decrease len list

it will print like this

```
print(data)
    ['1','A','A'],
    ['2','B','B'],
    ['3','C','C']

print(len(data))
3
```

I already try

```
for i in range(len(data)):
    if data[i][0].isdigit() == True:
        print(data)
```

its just show

```
print(data)
    ['1','A','A'],
    ['2','B','B'],
    ['3','C','C']
```

not decrease len

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
data = [['No','Name','Job'], ['1','A','A'], ['2','B','B'], ['IS','NOT','NUMBER'], ['3','C','C']]

print(len(data))
5

data = [x for x in data if x[0].isdigit()]
print(len(data))
3

print(data)
[['1', 'A', 'A'], ['2', 'B', 'B'], ['3', 'C', 'C']]
```

Answer (score 1):

Python List comprehension is being used here. Refer to https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-list-comprehension-and-slicing/ for more info on this.

```
data = [x for x in data if x[0].isdigit()]
print(len(data))
```

From the code that you have written, some modifications can be made and can be implemented without using list comprehensions also.

```
count =0
for i in data:
    if i[0].isdigit() == True:
        count +=1
        print(i)
print(count)
```

Hope this answer helps you.